# Kotlin thread status different state in fragment

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin

My goal is to update IU elements in a thread in Fragment (when it is visible). Basically I've got a thread that is supposed to run in loop. It checks if one of UI element is not null, or else terminates.

```
private val thread = Thread {
  while (txtHomeDest != null) {
    txtHomeDest.post { txtHomeDest.text = something }
    ...
    Thread.sleep(50)
  }
```

I start the thread in onStart or in onViewCreated. According to documentation only NEW thread can be started so I have a check:

```
override fun onStart() {
  super.onStart()
  println(thread.state)
  if (thread.state == Thread.State.NEW) thread.start()
}
```

Above method is working only if I open the fragment directly from it's UI button. In that case the above code in line "println(thread.state)" prints state NEW and everything is working as expected. But when I go to another fragment and click the back button, then I got state TERMINATED and new thread cannot be started. To start thread I have to click once again on UI element that opens that fragment. I hope it make sens, because it's hard for me to explain :) How to use threads correctly in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question. I've changed the code to:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  ...  
  updateHomeUI()
}
private fun updateHomeUI() {
  Thread {
    while (txtHomeDest != null) {
      txtHomeDest.post { txtHomeDest.text = something }
      ...
      Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
  }.start()
}
```

The thread will end when the fragment is changed or closed and will run again when fragment is opened or restored with "back" button (previous method did not work with "back" button).

Note that every time when the fragment is opened it creates a new thread. If I used while(true) I would have opened many background threads that could eventually slow down application etc.